# How to document OData endpoints (swagger, swashbuckle, other)?

Tags: odata, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

What is the best way of documenting OData endpoints?
Is there a way to use Swashbuckle for it?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, try [Swashbuckle.OData](https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData). It adds Swashbuckle support for ODataControllers.

See it in action here: http://swashbuckleodata.azurewebsites.net/swagger

Comment: Site is down, unfortunately

Comment: Swashbuckle.OData no longer works with the latest version of Microsoft.Odata.Core.  Apparently Microsoft changed the dependencies in Microsoft.AspNet.OData from System.Web.OData  and Swashbuckle.OData hasn't been updated to use the latest OData packages.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we are trying to support it like yaml -> Swagger, yaml -> csdl ..

But it will need time to implementation, you can see a prototype and track there https://github.com/OData/model-first

Answer (score 4):

I actually got something working for this using the IDocumentFilter function within Swashbuckle.  I answered a similar question on the GitHub repo for Swashbuckle.  Check out my response here (it's either at bottom or toward bottom):

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/149

I've posted an example of a working IDocumentFilter implementation that you could leverage to get your OData endpoint set up in the Swagger ui.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that I found is to convert OData definition to Open API spec using https://github.com/oasis-tcs/odata-openapi

Then import the spec document into swagger is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

## Asp NET and Asp NET Core Api Versioning

You can use [Api Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) (as it extends `ApiExplorer` with Odata information) for both **`WebApi`** and **`AspNetCore`**.

There are samples available for both:

- [WebApi](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation#aspnet-web-api-with-odata)
- [Asp Net Core](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation#aspnet-core-with-odata)

This [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerODataSample) how it integrates well with **Swashbuckle/Swagger ui**.